# Uniform continuity of $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|+1}$

Tags: real-analysis

$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|+1}$

Is uniform continuity?

We can not use derivative because at $x=0$ function $|x|$ is not differentiable. I attempted prove that $f$ is Lipschitz continuity but inequality is difficult.

Any hints?

Comment: Note that |f| < 1 in the uniform norm.

Comment: The function $g(x) = \sin(x^2)$ has that same property, but it's not uniformly continuous on the reals.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x}{1+x},&\text{ if }x\ge0\\\dfrac{x}{1-x},&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$

So for $x>0,~f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}<1~\forall~x>0$ and for $x<0,~f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}<1~\forall~x<0.$

$f'$ also exists at $0$ since

$$Rf'(0)=\lim_{x\to0+}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0+}\dfrac{1}{1+x}=0\\Lf'(0)=\lim_{x\to0-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0-}\dfrac{1}{1-x}=0$$are equal.

Consequently $f'(0)=1$ and hence $f'$ is bounded on $\mathbb R.$

Thus $f$ being a differentiable function having a bounded derivative on $\mathbb R,~f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Lovely, except that the limits are both 1 rather than 0, so $f'(0) = 1$. Everything else is spot on.

Comment: Suggestion appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition with $M = 1$. It certainly does on the positive reals. So if I were you, I'd prove uniform continuity by picking $\delta = \epsilon$, or perhaps $\delta = \epsilon / 2$ if you want a little breathing room.

Answer (score 0):

You can use derivatives, although $| x |$ is not differentiable at $0$,  $\,f (x)$ yes it is

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{|h|+1}=1$$